# blueimp jQuery-File-Upload can't find uploaded files

Tags: jquery, file-upload, upload, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

after installing blueimp jQuery-File-Upload on centos the upload seems working properly as i can see upload traffic on machine interface, **the problem is that  i can't find the uploaded files in /php/files directory**.

link on github : https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

1. what is the right directory of uploaded file?
2. if it is /php/files , why cant i see any files inside this directory?
3. how to change the default upload directory?

[root@localhost /]#  cd /var/www/html/upload/server/php/files/

[root@localhost files]# ls

[root@localhost files]#

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ius1h.png)

[upload progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ius1h.png)

Answer (score 0):

in fileupload options there is a url tag which you can use to post to your server method. (this is a .net example)

```
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: '@(Url.Content("~/"))controller_name/your_method_name'
    });
```

and in your method you can get uploaded files like:

```
var file = Request.Files[i]; // use in for loop
///// do some other thing ///
var filePath = your_path;
file.SaveAs(filePath);
```